# How to commit changes to Checkbox inside a Datagrid (not row selection) upon click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x

I have a Checkbox inside a cell on a table. When I click the checkbox, it changes, but only the first time. If I keep on clicking the same checkbox, nothing happens until I click outside that cell. I'm pretty sure that this has to do with [Row Editing](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/editing/#start-editing-2) (starting vs stopping), because the change only gets committed after I click away.

How do I overcome this? I don't need row editing or cell editing, but I do have these dropdown menus and this checkbox.

I feel like the answer might be one of these methods. Perhaps `forceUpdate`, `commitCellChange`, or `updateRows`? I've tried using them, but don't understand how to. https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/grid-api/

[image]

(P.S. There are some mistakes with this code, but it's close to my production code. I tried making a CodeSandbox but it was throwing a bunch of errors for importing the Datagrid.)

```
const rows = [
    {
      id: 1,
      fieldName: "ID"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      fieldName: "VisitId"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      fieldName: "First Name"
    }
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "fieldName",
      headerName: "fieldName",
      flex: 1,
      renderCell: (param: GridCellParams) => {
        const handleChange = (e: any): void => {
          myModel.checked= !myModel.checked
        };

        return (
          <Checkbox
            onClick={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            checked={myModel.checked}
          />
        );
      },
    }
  ];

<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have solved my own question, but I'm not really sure how it's working, so I'd love if someone else can explain, or provide another solution.

I added a call to `setCellFocus` from the [`GridApi` interface](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/grid-api/). Looks like modifying the cell focus tells the table to commit any changes, is my guess as to how this works.

```
{
      field: 'fieldName',
      headerName: 'fieldName',
      flex: 1,
      renderCell: (param: GridCellParams) => {
        const { id, value, api, field } = param;

        const handleChange = (e: any): void => {
          myModel.checked =
            !myModel.checked;

          api.setCellFocus(id, field);  // <---- I added this
        };

        return (
          <Checkbox
            onClick={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            checked={amyModel.checked}
          />
        );
      },
    },
```